# grabing a number six lines below a pattern

Tags: awk, text-extraction

I have these lines repeating

```
                               FINAL RESULTS



    NSTEP       ENERGY          RMS            GMAX         NAME    NUMBER
    1000      -4.7910E+01     2.1328E-01     9.4193E-01     C          62
```

The FINAL RESULTS indicate a average of those values for a set. The output file combines all 1000 sets. I need to grab the number below energy (-4.7910E+01), all 1000 of them in to another file. I need to set FINAL RESULTS as a pattern because other pattern such as NSTEP, ENERGY, RMS.... are repeated in millions.

I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on this, do you want *all* 1,000 lines below `ENERGY`, or just the first?

Comment: there is thousand of these in the file. I need all 1000 numbers below ENERGY.

Comment: Oh, I think I see, the entire `Final results\n...ENERGY\n...` pattern repeats?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
awk '/FINAL RESULTS/{for (i=0; i<5; i++) getline; print $2}' <filename>
```

Comment: This only prints a single value.

Comment: @potong Thanks for your comment. I tested it with multiple values and worked fine. Could you let me know an input example that doesn't produce the expected outcome?

Comment: I owe you an apology. I thought there were a thousand lines under `ENERGY` not that there were a 1000 `FINAL RESULTS`'s.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I think I see now.

```
awk 'found==1 { print $2; found=0 } $2=="ENERGY" { found=1 }' inputfile
```

This will get the number below `ENERGY` regardless of how many lines there are between it and `FINAL RESULTS`.

Comment: This doesn't use the pattern "FINAL RESULTS" so it will output the values under "ENERGY" for other sections ("NSTEP", etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
awk '/FINAL RESULTS/{f=1;p=0}{p++}f==1 && p==6{print $2}' file
```

Or if you like:

```
awk 'f==2 && p==1{print $2}{p++}/FINAL RESULTS/{f=1}/ENERGY/ && f==1{f=2;p=0}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `grep` (and some others following its extensions) you could just do something like `grep -A 6 'FINAL RESULTS'`

So that should work for Linux, and I see that it works on a recent MacOS X and I'm pretty sure I've used it on FreeBSD.  So it probably works on most forms of UNIX you're going to encounter.  (If not, install the GNU "coreutils" package).